# TypeScript and Express, Testing and exporting a router module

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, mocha.js

I'm getting my head around Node, Express and TypeScript, in doing so I'm looking to build up some tests.

To follow best practices, SOLID etc I've separated my routers from my controllers.

I have an index.ts file

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import { TestController } from '../controllers/test.controller';

let testController = new TestController();

let index = Router();

/* GET home page. */
index.get('/', (req, res, next) => testController.get(req, res));

export default index;
```

I also have an index.spec.ts file

```
import assert = require('assert');
import * as mocha from 'mocha';

import { index } from '../routes/index';
import { TestController } from '../controllers/test.controller';


import { Request, Response } from 'express';

var sinon = require('sinon');
var should = require('should');

import app from '../App';

describe('Indexrouter', function () {
    describe('#Calling get /', function () {
        it('should call test controller get function.', function () {

        });
    });
});
```

When I try and run the tests via gulp i get the following messages

```
"D:/Dev/Learning/node/ts-express/src/routes/index.ts(4,7): Exported variable 'index' has or is using name 'Router' from external module \"express-serve-static-core\" but cannot be named."
"D:/Dev/Learning/node/ts-express/src/routes/index.spec.ts(4,10): Module '\"D:/Dev/Learning/node/ts-express/src/routes/index\"' has no exported member 'index'."
"D:/Dev/Learning/node/ts-express/src/app.ts(24,14): Cannot find name 'index'."
```

I can run the server ok and it will produce the correct endpoint with response.  Although I do get the working about exported variable 'index'. It just seems that in the tests I can't import the index module for some reason.

- How can I fix the module so I don't get the exported variable error.
- How can I actually test that the index route calls the get method on the controller.

I have managed to get the controller tests working and the project as a whole can be seen [here](https://github.com/digitalinfamy/express-ts-mocha)